# Calculate the Cyclomatic Complexity

Tags: cyclomatic-complexity

Calculate the CC (Cyclomatic Complexity) of the following code snippets.

I am not sure if I have drawn the Control Flow Graph correctly and furthermore if my calculation for the Cyclomatic Complexity is correct. And as for the formula `M = E - N + 2P`, the P is defined as "`P = number of nodes that have exit points`". Am I only counting the return here? How is it then with GCD2, if the method calls itself recursively does this also count as a return?

GCD1

```
public class GCD1 {
    public int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (a < b) {
            int t = a;
            a = b;
            b = t;
        }
        while (a % b != 0) {
            int r = a % b;
            a = b;
            b = r;
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

GCD2

```
public class GCD2 {
    public int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (a < b)
            return gcd(b, a);
        else if (b == 0)
            return a;
        else
            return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}
```

---

**Calculation**

M = E – N + 2P

where,

- E = the number of edges in the control flow graph
- N = the number of nodes in the control flow graph
- P = number of nodes that have exit points

*Control Flow Graph of above GCD1*

M = 7 - 6 + 2*1 = 3

[image]

*Control Flow Graph of above GCD2*

M = 8 - 7 + 2*1 = 3

[image]

Comment: Hey, this question would be better suited to [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). =)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68242940/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/141983/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @Elliott, may I make a request for the future?  If you're going to suggest another site, it would be nice if you could let people know not to cross-post: you can suggest they delete the copy here before posting elsewhere.  I'm hoping that will lead to a better experience for both the poster and for answerers.  Thank you!

Comment: @D.W., thanks for the feedback. Good point. 'Will do.